# "return false;" ignored when function is present even if function is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, frontend

I have a click event handler for an anchor that grabs the selector's ID as a variable, has an `if` parameter and runs 2 functions with `return false;` at the end to prevent the window from refreshing:

```
function ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber) {

    var state = {ItemNumberHistory: ItemNumber};

    var title = null;

    var path = '/Inventory/' + ItemNumber;

    history.pushState(state, title, path); // Add item number to URL/history

}

$(document).on('click', '.StoneLink', function(event) {
    
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id'); // Get item number from ID;
    
    // Toggle nav on mobile
    if($(navContent).is(':visible')) {
        $(navContent).addClass('navHide'); // Hide nav on mobile
        $('#navToggleIcon').toggleClass('mdi-close mdi-menu'); // Toggle nav menu icon
    }
    
    ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);
    
    loadItem(ItemNumber);

    return false;
    
});
```

For some reason though this still refreshes the window [although `return false;` is expected to prevent that], but when I comment out `ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);` (line 23) the `return false;` doesn't refresh the window.

`return false;` doesn't work when I delete the contents of `ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);` either. It seems that i'm having the issue simply because the function is inside the click event handler.

How do I run my click event handler without the window refreshing on click?!

### CODE SNIPPET

```js
var ItemNumberHistory = '';

function loadItem(ItemNumber) {

    ItemNumberHistory = ItemNumber;

    $('#pageRoot').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');

    $('.LoadItem, #StonePage').show(); // Show modal and loader

    $.ajax({

        url: 'vendors/pages/Inventory/LandingPage/Item.php?number=' + ItemNumber, 
        method: 'POST',
        data: {ItemNumber: ItemNumber},  
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        error: 

            function(jqXHR, strError) {
                
                if(strError == 'timeout') {
                    // Do something. Try again perhaps?
                    alert('Seems like there was an error loading this stones information.');
                }
                
            },

        success:

            function(data) {

                $('#StoneDetails').html(data);

            },
            
        timeout: 3000

    });
    
}

function ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber) {

    var state = {ItemNumberHistory: ItemNumber};

    var title = null;

    var path = '/Inventory/' + ItemNumber;

    history.replaceState(state, title, path); // Add item number to URL/history

}

$(document).on('click', '.StoneLink', function(event) {
    
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id'); // Get item number from ID;
    
    // Toggle nav on mobile
    if($(navContent).is(':visible')) {
        $(navContent).addClass('navHide'); // Hide nav on mobile
        $('#navToggleIcon').toggleClass('mdi-close mdi-menu'); // Toggle nav menu icon
    }
    
    ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);
    
    loadItem(ItemNumber);

    return false;
    
});

function closeModal() {
    
    if($('#StonePage').is(':visible')) {

        $('#StonePage').hide();
        
        $('#pageRoot').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        
        history.replaceState(null, null, '/Inventory'); // Remove ItemNumber from URL path

    }

}

// Hide modal when close button
$(document).on('click', '#CloseModal', function() {
    closeModal();
});

// Hide modal on click away
$(document).on('click', '.head, #StonePage', function(event) {

    // If clicked anywhere [on #StonePage] outside of .modal
    if(!$('.modal').is(event.target) && $('.modal').has(event.target).length === 0) {
        closeModal();
    }

});

// Hide modal on esc key press
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) { 

    // keyCode 27 is esc key
    if(event.keyCode == 27) { 
        closeModal();
    }

});
```

```css
.modalContainer {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 130px 0 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.modal {
    width: 700px;
    height: 375px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.StoneDetails {
}

/* .CloseModal height and width are 36px */
.CloseModal {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    color: #ff0000;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.CloseModal:hover { 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}

.CloseModal:active {    
    color: #000;
}
    
/* Load Item */     
.LoadItem {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 375px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 164px;
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 4;
    border: 0px solid red;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.noScroll {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Inventory">

    <div id="StonePage" class="modalContainer" tabindex="0">

        <div class="modal">

            <div id="CloseModal" class="CloseModal" title="Close">
                <span class="mdi mdi-36px mdi-close"></span>
            </div>
                
            <div id="StoneDetails" class="StoneDetails">
            
                <!-- Content appends here -->
                
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="InventoryContent">

        <!-- Stone listings -->
        <div id="StoneContainer">
        
            <div class="Stone" id="StoneIteration" data-listing="1" data-totalrows="1">

                <!-- Stone's landing page -->
                <a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/Inventory/Item Number" class="StoneLink" id="Item Number">
                                    
                    <!-- Image -->
                    <div class="StoneData StoneIMG">
                        <img src="image.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Weight --> 
                    <div class="StoneData">
                        Weight
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Type -->
                    <div class="StoneData">
                        Type
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Enhancement -->
                    <div class="StoneData">
                        Enhancement
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Dimensions -->
                    <div class="StoneData">
                        Dimensions
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Item Number -->
                    <div class="StoneData">
                        #Item Number
                    </div>

                </a>

            </div>

        </div>
            
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you're probably handling a `click` event inside a `<form>` ... you need to prevent the form default submit action

Comment: Can you add the HTML associated with this code?

Comment: `return false;` doesn't work when I delete the contents of ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber); either. - Not sure I follow. Do you mean just having an empty function?

Comment: @Bravo the HTML anchor isn't ina `<form>` though. I also tried `event.preventDefault` in the click event handler with no success.

Comment: Oh, right, so it's the pushState that's doing it because you are changing the URL

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe There's a lot of PHP in it. Here's a dump of it: [Listing.php](https://pastebin.com/5btYrTMk)

Comment: @TonyM Yeah, if I delete everything inside the function and click the anchor the window still refreshes but if I simply delete the function it doesn't [as expected]

Comment: @Bravo but if I comment out the `history.pushState()` I still have the issue...

Comment: `ItemNumberHistory` return false

Comment: @TonyM I tried that too - it still refreshes the window. I also attempted `return false;` at the end of `ItemNumberHistory()` while having `event.preventDefault` in the click handler with no success.

Comment: @user3570240 try using `history.replaceState()` instead of  `history.pushState()`

Comment: @dippas `history.replaceState(state, title, path);` still doesn't work. I also tried emptying out `function ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber) {}` and the window still refreshes on click. The anchor seems to only `return false;` on click when I remove `ItemNumberHistory();` from the click event handler completely, but I need `history.pushState()` as having the back button bind `loadItem(ItemNumber);` is important to the project.

Comment: Please include the HTML in the form of a stack-snippet that demonstrates the issue, edit the question and click `[<>]` - include enough code (html/js) so we can see it happening - you may need two separate snippets to show when it is / isn't working.  See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added a code snippet. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.
'a href' is suspected.

change your tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="StoneLink" id="<?php echo $row['number']; ?>">
(or <a href="#" class="StoneLink" id="<?php echo $row['number']; ?>">)
```

and change your event function

```
$('.StoneLink').on('click', function(event) {
    
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id'); // Get item number from ID;
    
    // Toggle nav on mobile
    if($(navContent).is(':visible')) {
        $(navContent).addClass('navHide'); // Hide nav on mobile
        $('#navToggleIcon').toggleClass('mdi-close mdi-menu'); // Toggle nav menu icon
    }
    
    ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);
    
    loadItem(ItemNumber);

    location.href = '/Inventory/'+ItemNumber; // '<a href="">' instead

    return false;
    
});
```

Comment: I realize that the anchor is suspected but I need it to be an anchor as I do have external pages. However on the page with `class="StoneLink"` the data in those external pages is shown in a _modal_.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code you posted and there are a bunch of small, semantic issues (not the culprit here though). I was able to run most of it successfully on my local machine. A couple things:

1. Make sure you're stopping propagation correctly i.e. `event.preventDefault()`, not `event.preventDefault`.
2. `navContent` isn't defined (at least within the snippet provided).
3. Do you need `ItemNumberHistory` both as a variable and function definition? It's confusing.

I think if you add this you'll be fine:

```js
$('.StoneLink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ItemNumber = $(this).attr('id'); // Get item number from ID;
    
    // Toggle nav on mobile
    if($(navContent).is(':visible')) {
        $(navContent).addClass('navHide'); // Hide nav on mobile
        $('#navToggleIcon').toggleClass('mdi-close mdi-menu'); // Toggle nav menu icon
    }
    
    ItemNumberHistory(ItemNumber);
    
    loadItem(ItemNumber);

    location.href = '/Inventory/'+ItemNumber; // '<a href="">' instead

    return false;
    
});
```

Comment: > 2. `navContent` isn't defined (at least within the snippet provided).
Sorry, I defined that in another document. I doubt it's relevant but: `var navContent = $('#navContent');` 

> 3. Do you need `ItemNumberHistory` both as a variable and function definition? It's confusing.
No I just did that quickly, I can change it.

As for the solution, for me it doesn't open the anchor or run any of the code at all [it doesn't refresh the window either]. I'm assuming that's because `event.preventDefault()` is before the rest of the code.

Comment: "...code at all [it doesn't refresh the window either..." <-- I think that's an indication that it works as intended. Code below should still run but something is buggy. Debugging should show what the issue is, or even console logging some generic string to verify code execution at the point. I think there are other problems on the larger context here.

Comment: In other words, the original problem (page reloading) is fixed. But now it appears there are other issues. e.g: Check that `ItemNumber` has an actual value, debug  `ItemNumberHistory()` to see where code breaks, etc.

Comment: When putting it in CodePen and clicking the anchor I get "Uncaught TypeError: ItemNumberHistory is not a function". Would you know why i'm getting that error?

https://codepen.io/brilliantmojo/pen/MWjwxpy?editors=1010

Comment: Because you have it declared globally as a variable. Change this to something else: `var ItemNumberHistory = '';`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Changed it to `var ItemNumberState`. This fixed the issue of refreshing window [on the first anchor click] but every time I click the anchor after that the window refreshes. Also, now I don't think either functions are running.